# python string to indexer

Tags: pandas, numpy

I want to use a string input as parameter for selecting a range of columns from a pandas dataframe. Something like:

```
columns ="3:10"

pd.iloc[:,columns]
```

but I am getting an error because columns is of type string and it is not a valid type.

Comment: `iloc[:, int(columns.split(':')[0]):int(columns.split(':')[1])]`

Comment: I want to do it generic, and if the dataframe is of higher dimension, the input string could be variable in number of :

Comment: How are you separating the pair values?  if you use a `;` you could use something like ``` [item for sublist in [list(range(int(x.split(':')[0]), int(x.split(':')[1]))) for x in columns.split(';')] for item in sublist] ```